# Clipping shapefile – QGIS vs Python

Tags: qgis, python, clip

Which algorithm does QGIS use for clipping shapefiles?

When I use ogr2ogr to clip a large shapefile (approx. 3gb) it takes 77sec. When using QGIS it takes approx 5 sec, clipping the same dataset (and same mask-layer). New clipped layer is approx 30mb, and the 6sec. includes saving in QGIS

Any suggestions for a better algorithms or modifications of the code below?

Here is the code I use in Python:

```
import subprocess
clipping_shp = r"C:\Python\buffer.shp"
output_shp = r"C:\Python\result.shp"  
input_shp = r'C:\Python\data.shp'
subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", clipping_shp, output_shp, input_shp], shell=True)
```

Comment: Do you save clipped layer when you use qgis? I mean is it a memory layer or a saved layer on disk? Saving layer consumes a lot time and you are using 3 gb file.

Comment: Does 5 sec with QGIS include the time it took to open the layer into QGIS?

Comment: You don't use a Python solution, you use ogr2ogr via Python

Comment: @Xi Jin, New clipped layer is approx 30mb, and the 6sec. includes saving in QGIS.@user30184 It includes the clip-prosess and saving new layer

Answer (score 1):

> Which algorithm does QGIS use for clipping shapefiles?

QGIS is Open Source and you can have a look through the code for the clipping algorithm on their GitHub:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/04b9c6ab00bb130e590863244b8de64c0f111ae1/src/analysis/processing/qgsalgorithmclip.cpp